# Why should you avoid "stringently columnar" input formats?

Tags: text-processing, history, columns, unix-philosophy

> Doug McIlroy, the inventor of Unix pipes and one of the founders of the Unix tradition, had this to say at the time [McIlroy78]:
>
> (ii) Expect the output of every program to become the input to another, as yet unknown, program. Don't clutter output with extraneous information. Avoid stringently columnar or binary input formats. Don't insist on interactive input.

Stringently columnar data sounds good to me, so I probably do not understand what he meant.

What does it mean and why is it bad?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume he meant *aligned* columns, not columnar data in general. That's how I would understand the *stringently* anyway. For example:

**Bad:**

```
1    200 3
100  3   400
```

**Good:**

```
1 200 3
100 3 400
```

In other words, make files that are easy for computers to read, not for humans. Adding spaces to align things makes them pretty and easier for you and me to understand but can confuse programs that need to parse them.

For example, if I were to use `cut` to get the second field of each of the above examples, it would fail on the first:

```
$ cut -d' ' -f 2 bad


$ cut -d' ' -f 2 good 
200
3
```

Because of the extra spaces, the 2nd field of the `bad` file is a space. However, it works as expected in the `good` file.

Comment: He means fixed-width records.  These were widely used in the days of Fortran IV and punched cards.  Their evil ways still live on with AIX. ;)

Comment: @lcd047 that's what I describe isn't it? Or are fixed-width records something else?

Comment: No, it's more like a wall of numbers, where columns 1-4 mean X, column 5 means Y, columns 6-12 is Z etc.  No separators.  Processing these is fine, but data entry is a pain in the rear.  Remember that back then data entry wasn't interactive.  Trust me, you'd run screaming the first time you'd have to deal with that. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Stringently Columnar

`fixed with` and `ordered columns` vs `dynamic width` and `headers`

## Example

### Fixed width

name (7 bytes) [space] age (2 bytes) [space] height (5 bytes)

```
alice   10 150cm 
bob     20 160cm
carol   30 170cm
```

if I now need to add `Alexander` age `40` height `180cm`

```
alice   10 150cm 
bob     20 160cm
carol   30 170cm
Alexa~1 40 180cm
```

it doesn't fit in the stringently columnar structure you run out of space
if you use a more flexible columnar structure

### Space Separated Values

this pain can be avoided with a space separated values

```
alice 10 150cm 
bob 20 160cm
carol 30 170cm
Alexander 40 180cm
```

### Space(s) Separated Values

or a format that divided columns with 1 or more space

```
alice     10 150cm 
bob       20 160cm
carol     30 170cm
Alexander 40 180cm
```

since the number of spaces doesn't matter we may format for human readability or for file density as suits our needs
even better still in the eyes of the Unix philosophy is a format that doesn't force the order or presence of columns
if the first row is the names of the columns and then the data space(s) delimited file

```
Name      Age Height
alice     10  150cm 
bob       20  160cm
carol     30  170cm
Alexander 40  180cm
```

with

```
Age Height Name      
10  150cm  alice
20  160cm  bob
30  170cm  carol
40  180cm  Alexander
```

just as valid as the first
If we have extra columns we don't care about the headers give us more flexibility

```
Age Height t_shirt_size Name      
10  150cm  S            alice
20  160cm  M            bob
30  170cm  L            carol
40  180cm  XL           Alexander
```

we can still read out the `Name`, `Age`, and `Height` and just ignore the columns that have headers that we don't care about. still loads to the object

```
[{"Name":"alice",    "Age":10, "Height":"150cm"},
 {"Name":"bob",      "Age":20, "Height":"160cm"},
 {"Name":"carol",    "Age":30, "Height":"170cm"},
 {"Name":"Alexander","Age":40, "Height":"180cm"}]
```

These rules lead to a file format like CSV https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180

```
Age,Height,t shirt size,Name      
10,150 cm,S,alice
20,160 cm,M,bob
30,170 cm,L,carol
40,180 cm,XL,Alexander
```

by avoiding `stringently columnar data` we make it more likely that the as yet unknown, program we expect the output to become the input to can work with our unmodified program.

If my program puts out data in CSV it can be read and graphed by countless programs I don't even know exist.